# Choose SQL Server query with lower logical read or lower execution time

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries from table A and table B with the exact same output. The structure and data in both table are same, but table A is a heap table with no index. Table B is also a heap table, but has a nonclustered index.

Query A has lower logical reads, but execution time is longer

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(362805 rows affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 20619, logical reads 2070752, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 17244, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'test_orders_cluster'. Scan count 2, logical reads 13367, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'costanlcdate'. Scan count 2, logical reads 294, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 6609 ms,  elapsed time = 38801 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

Completion time: 2021-05-30T12:30:10.3830717+07:00
```

Query A execution plan:
[image: Query A]

Query B has triple the amount of logical reads, but lower execution time:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(362805 rows affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1419102, logical reads 6360963, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'test_costanlcdate'. Scan count 2, logical reads 15770, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'test_orders_cluster'. Scan count 2, logical reads 13367, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 9766 ms,  elapsed time = 34790 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

Completion time: 2021-05-30T12:30:10.2686723+07:00
```

Query B execution plan:
[image: Query B]

Could you please tell me which one to pick and why? Thank you.

Comment: These are always going to be difficult without having the data etc to play with. Things I'd look at a) Why no clustered index? It gives you a relatively free sort b) First query looks better on scans/reads, but spills to disk on the sort (noting that the disk spill takes about 9s of the 13s runtime). Can you adjust to stop it spilling to disk? c) Both queries have large nested loops. Can these work better with other types of joins e.g., give it a `LEFT OUTER HASH JOIN` hint instead (sometimes these help if you cannot adjust indexes).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full queries *as text*, along with table and index definitions, and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. We can't work with pictures and a little bit of output from `SET STATISTICS` there's not enough info.

Comment: You appear to have a self-join going on, and clearly indexing could be better. The first query has that big spilled sort which is probably causing issues, and there's a few `Filter` and ` Compute Scalar` which could probably be gotten rid of, guessing that's because of conversions.